# how to get a random element in an array and how to get a random row from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, random

I have been asked to get related stuff to what the user has in his items

so as far as the database was created this items table stores the category name so,
i thought to get the category name and save it into an array

and then do a for loop and get one random value from it

and after that get a random row from mysql database so anyone has an idea how to do this

in other words i want to know how to get a random value from an array and a random row from mysql

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
 $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
```

see example http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php
for php and for mysql

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

use this

Comment: to select a random _row_ from an array, you should  `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: @sujal Thanks a lot for your reply i will try this and inform you about the result

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Thanks a lot for informing me about the LIMIT 1 part you have saved the day

Comment: @MohamedHassan I am waiting for your answer

Comment: can i ask about what it does return a row or number?

Comment: Sorry guys i got it at first wrong and then i edited it and it worked just amazing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9838/discussion-between-sujal-and-mohamed-hassan)

Comment: Click to continue this discussion in chat...because this conversation is becoming longer

Answer (score 2):

To get a random element from an array in PHP you can use [array_rand](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

To get a random row from a MySQL query you can use [RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) so something like

```
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

But note that this method in MySQL can have performance implications.

Comment: what implications you mean?? and do you think there is a better approach?

Comment: @MohamedHassan Performance can degrade if your table gets big: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/ On small tables it's not a worry but if there's any chance your table might grow then you might want to think about an alternative from the outset.

Answer (score 0):

quote from http://php.net/manual/de/function.rand.php:

> ilya dot iz at i dot ua 27-Jul-2011 08:09
>   I had to come up with a quick way to get a random row from a table, and came up with the following: ...

Should be easy to get a random value from an array with something like rand(0,count(arrayvar))